# Crystal report scroll like header

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create crystal report that has dynamical scroll like header section.

i want a header section that depending on its size may go on second page just like detail section does. the twist is that header consists from multiple small header sections that are not static :/ sometimes one of those might be suppressed and other times not.

for example:

we have H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 D1 F1

i do not want header 1 to be repeated on every page which i can easily suppress
but what can i do for header section 2 ?

I do not know will it be printed on second page or on first ? it may be also printed on third, depending on the length of first header section.

so what i want to know is:

1) how can i dynamically grow header section on next page

2) restrict section from repeating after first print

if anyone knows how to do this please help

thank you in advance